# Split a sentence on capital letters

Tags: python, string, split

How can I split this?

```
'Symptoms may include:Absent or small knucklesCleft palateDecreased skin creases at finger jointsDeformed earsDroopy eyelidsInability to fully extend the joints from birth (contracture deformity)Narrow shouldersPale skinTriple-jointed thumbs'
```

Desired Output should take this form

```
Symptoms may include:
Absent or small knuckles
Cleft palate
Decreased skin creases at finger joints
Deformed ears
Droopy eyelids
Inability to fully extend the joints from birth (contracture deformity)
Narrow shoulders
Pale skin
Triple-jointed thumbs
```

Like split on Capital letters.

Comment: Have you already tried to solve it somehow? Share your attempt. Stackoverflow is not a "write it for me" service.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `re.findall` (pattern improved thanks to @Brendan Abel and @JFF):

```
fragments = re.findall('[A-Z][^A-Z]*', text)
```

```
print(fragments)
['Symptoms may include:',
 'Absent or small knuckles',
 'Cleft palate',
 'Decreased skin creases at finger joints',
 'Deformed ears',
 'Droopy eyelids',
 'Inability to fully extend the joints from birth (contracture deformity)',
 'Narrow shoulders',
 'Pale skin',
 'Triple-jointed thumbs']
```

**Details**

```
[A-Z]      # match must begin with a uppercase char
[^A-Z]*    # further characters in match must not contain an uppercase char
```

Note: `*` lets you capture sentences with a single upper-case character. Substitute with `+` if that is not desired functionality.

Also, if you want your output as a multiline string:

```
print('\n'.join(fragments))
```

Comment: You could avoid the lookahead and just test for non-capitals `[A-Z][^A-Z]+`

Comment: Dang it! I almost beat, I was just a copy-n-paste away ;-) +1

Comment: @BrendanAbel Thanks, that's a great improvement.

Comment: how to split "A new issue" ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Added in a note, thanks for that!

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ bar that, I'm stupid: your previous pattern works because space is matched by uppercase negation. But greediness of regex makes the new pattern work as well

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre No worries. I also find it funny how my answer receives one solitary downvote, in conjunction with the other answerers deleting their posts.

Comment: get used to it: people don't like you for being so prolific :) such downvotes generally backfire

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Hah, well, _they'll_ have to get used to that :p

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> s = 'Symptoms may include:Absent or small knucklesCleft palateDecreased skin creases at finger jointsDeformed earsDroopy eyelidsInability to fully extend the joints from birth (contracture deformity)Narrow shouldersPale skinTriple-jointed thumbs'
>>> print(''.join(('\n' + c if c.isupper() else c) for c in s)[1:])
Symptoms may include:
Absent or small knuckles
Cleft palate
Decreased skin creases at finger joints
Deformed ears
Droopy eyelids
Inability to fully extend the joints from birth (contracture deformity)
Narrow shoulders
Pale skin
Triple-jointed thumbs
```

#### How it works

- `(('\n' + c if c.isupper() else c) for c in s)`

  The above generates a list of each character `c` in string `s` except if `c` is upper case in which case it prepends a new line to that character.
- `''.join(('\n' + c if c.isupper() else c) for c in s))`

  This joins the list back together into a string.
- `''.join(('\n' + c if c.isupper() else c) for c in s)[1:]`

  This removes the extra newline from the beginning of the string.

Answer (score -1):

I think the following code can be interesting

```
import re
output = re.sub( r"([A-Z])", r"\n\1", inputString)
print(output)
```

you can also store it back in list by splitting all the `\n`

```
outputList = output.split('\n')[1::]
```

This initially replaces all the capital letters with a `\n` and then the capital letter

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Have you tested it?..(hint: it does work...https://ideone.com/ybk5t3)........

Comment: My bad, I was too sure of myself, yes it works. But you're using regex, _then_ split, _then_ slicing. I wouldn't recommend that way of doing it.

Comment: `output = re.sub( r"([A-Z])", r"\n\1", inputString).split('\n')[1:]` unfortunately needs a sub + split call to work (not to mention, the empty string up front).

Comment: @Yes..It is almost 3.7 times slower than the `findall` but I was trying to find another way out. but let me tell you that the time complexity is dominated by `re.sub( r"([A-Z])", r"\n\1", inputString)` not the splitting or slicing.